# event stoppropagation not working with checkboxes in a table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angular-material2, stoppropagation

I have a table with a checkbox and button. I tried using event.stoppropagation in the button and it works fine but when i set the exact same thing on checkboxes, it does not work. Any idea how to solve this? Code as below:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort  (matSortChange)="sortData($event)">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > No. </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" fxFlex="5" fxFlexOffset="2">
                  <mat-checkbox name="checkbox_data" id="checkbox_{{element.sid}}" [(ngModel)]="element.selected" (change)="checkIfAllSelected($event)"></mat-checkbox>
              </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="unit_num">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header="unit_num"> Unit No. </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.unit_num}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="unit_type">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="unit_type"> Unit Type </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.unit_type}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="shares">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="shares"> Shares </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.shares}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="sections">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Section </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.sections.section_type}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="buildings">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Building </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.buildings.buildingname}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="actions_delete">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef fxFlex="3" fxFlexOffset="2" mat-sort-header> {{ 'Actions' | TranslateText }} </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"fxFlex="3" fxFlexOffset="2">
                            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="deleteStaff($event, element.sid)">{{'Delete' | TranslateText}}</button>
                    </mat-cell>
                  </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let index=index;" mat-ripple style="position:relative;" (click)="edit(row._id,$event)"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
```

Both functions has event.stopPropagation(); in them.

Comment: Your post doesn't tell us much about what you are doing. Please explain what "doesn't work" means. Does it throw errors? What are you trying to achieve functionally by stopping the event? What steps have you taken to verify that the MatCheckboxChange event propogates? A working stackblitz example will go a long way toward someone giving you the help you need.

Comment: Note that the [MatCheckboxChange](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api#MatCheckboxChange) event does not have a `stopPropogation()` function.